# Actualizar registro php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

estaba necesitando modificar el registro de unas columnas de una base de datos, hice esto:

```html
 CONEXION.PHP
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$bd = "base";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die("No se conecto");

?>
```

```html
FORMULARIO
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>modificar</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="" action="modificar.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id">
  <input type="text" name="equipo_local" placeholder="equipo_local">
  <input type="text" name="escudo_local" placeholder="escudo_local">
  <input type="text" name="equipo_visitante" placeholder="equipo_visitante">
  <input type="text" name="escudo_visitante" placeholder="escudo_visitante">
  <input type="submit" name="name" value="modificar">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
MODIFICAR.PHP
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$equipo_local = $_POST['equipo_local'];
$escudo_local = $_POST['escudo_local'];
$equipo_visitante = $_POST['equipo_visitante'];
$escudo_visitante = $_POST['escudo_visitante'];

mysql_select_db($db, $conexion) or die("error");
mysql_query("UPDATE adiccion_partidos SET equipo_local = '$equipo_local', escudo_local='$escudo_local',equipo_visitante = '$equipo_visitante', escudo_visitante='$escudo_visitante' WHERE id = '$id' ");
echo "bien"

?>
```

Pero no funciona, y de la base de datos "Base" me necesito conectar a una tabla que se llama por ejemplo "equipos" y modificar esos datos.

Comment: Cual es el error que arroja la aplicación o el motor BD?

Comment: `  thrown in /home/adiccion/public_html/matias/directorio/edlp/admin/modificar.php on line 11
[26-Jul-2018 14:56:58 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in /home/adiccion/public_html/modificar.php:11`

Comment: de donde sacas las variable '$db' en el string :
`mysql_select_db($db, $conexion) or die("error");`  ???? en el `modificar.php`

Comment: Este es el error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in /home/adiccion/public_html/matias/directorio/admin/modificar.php:9`

Comment: Eso está en un include, el archivo se llama "conexion.php"

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de PHP? Si es la `v. 7+` tu código no funcionará porque la extensión `mysql_*` fue sacada definitivamente del núcleo de PHP 7. Es casi seguro el motivo del error *`Undefined function`*

Comment: Supestamente es el 5.x, ahora me fijo, en todo casa, si fuera la 7.x como armaría eso?

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esta en modificar.php:

```
 <?php
 include ("conexion.php");
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $equipo_local = $_POST['equipo_local'];
 $escudo_local = $_POST['escudo_local'];
 $equipo_visitante = $_POST['equipo_visitante'];
 $escudo_visitante = $_POST['escudo_visitante'];

 mysqli_select_db($bd, $conexion) or die("error");
 mysqli_query("UPDATE adiccion_partidos SET equipo_local = '$equipo_local', 
 escudo_local='$escudo_local',equipo_visitante = '$equipo_visitante', 
 escudo_visitante='$escudo_visitante' WHERE id = '$id' ");
 echo "bien"

 ?>
```

Comment: Me dice "error" que es lo que puse en "or die();" en conexion.php

Comment: cambio el error? ahora no estas llegando a la base de datos? de ser así, era por la versión que utilizas. y ahora el error esta en los datos de conexion.

Comment: intenta ahora modificando la sintaxis en `conexion.php` : 
`$conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$bd) `

Comment: Eso lo pusieron arriba y no me funcionó, será porque esa base tiene 4 tablas mas? Yo quiero actualizar la tabla 3 de esa base

Comment: ojo, que solucionaste tu problema principal de la funcion, ahora tu error es otro a nivel de conexion, por lo que me estas diciendo se te esta cayendo cuando intentas conectar al motor, puedes verificar eso? imprimete el error a nivel de aplicación con los datos que hemos actualizado incluyendo el de arriba.

Comment: Si, es eso, cuando le doy a "modificar" me va a "/modificar.php y me dice "error" que es lo que puse.

Comment: De verdad das esa respuesta?

Comment: Si, el error no es en $db o $bd

Comment: puedes pegar un print de las tablas de la bd? para verificar el query..
intentaste poniendo el nombre de la bd cuando llamas la tabla en el query?

Comment: No puedo pegar una imagen acá

Comment: puedes compilar el mismo query en el motor de bd y ver que te arroja?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80724/discussion-between-matiphp-and-francisco-acevedo).

Answer (score 0):

La estructura para mysqli_connect() es:
mysqli_connect(Servidor, Usuario, Contraseña, BasedeDatos)

Por tanto te falta poner la base de datos en la que estarás trabajando

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$bd) or die("No se conecto");
```

CONEXION.PHP

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$bd = "base";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$bd) or die("No se conecto");

?>
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error, "error"

Comment: En tu archivo modificar haz esto: $mysqli = new mysqli(servidor, usuario, contraseña, baseDatos);

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
//Cuando ya conexion sea establecida podras ejeuctar tus query
$sentenciaSql = "UPDATE adiccion_partidos SET equipo_local = '$equipo_local', 
 escudo_local='$escudo_local',equipo_visitante = '$equipo_visitante', 
 escudo_visitante='$escudo_visitante' WHERE id = '$id' ";
if ($mysqli->query($sentenciaSql) === TRUE) {
    printf("Se modifico.\n");
}

Comment: Para poder identificar cual es el problema, si la conexión o la sentencia.

Comment: Lo probé y no me imprime nada en la pantalla, quedo así:

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, adiccion_af, pass, adiccion_partidos); /* comprobar la conexión */ if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); exit(); } //Cuando ya conexion sea establecida podras ejeuctar tus query 

 $sentenciaSql = "UPDATE adiccion_partidos SET equipo_local = '$equipo_local', escudo_local='$escudo_local',equipo_visitante = '$equipo_visitante', escudo_visitante='$escudo_visitante' WHERE id = '$id' "; if ($mysqli->query($sentenciaSql) === TRUE) { printf("Se modifico.\n"); } `

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, adiccion_af, pass, adiccion_partidos); 
/* comprobar la conexión */ 
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { 
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); 
    exit(); 
} /* Cuando ya conexion sea establecida podras ejeuctar tus query */
$sentenciaSql = "UPDATE ....."; 

if ($mysqli->query($sentenciaSql) === TRUE) { 
    printf("Se modifico.\n"); 
}else{
    printf("Error en la sentencia sql.\n"); 
}

Comment: Intenta ahora así, le agregue el else de que si falla la sentencia sql

Comment: No puedes ponerlo en una respuesta, ya que de ahi se deforma un poco la respuesta

Comment: Error en la sentencia sql es el error que me da

Comment: Entonces revisa tu sentencia SQL ahí pueda que este el problema

Comment: La sentencia es donde tengo el "UPDATE...."?

Comment: Si, es donde tienes el update